# Magic: the Gathering - Barren Glory

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Your goal. Win the game with [Barren Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136048) using a [Modern legal deck](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/modern) on turn 2's upkeep using the least number of cards possible. (I don't think turn 1 is possibble but please prove me wrong).

Assume your opponent has a deck containing only basic lands and you decide whether you begin or are on the draw.

Using a card means using its effect. If a card is discarded, exiled, milled or anything else to pay for an additional cost or because of an effect of another card it is not counted towards your card count.

My personal solution uses 8 cards and has a total converted mana cost of 21. Good luck!

If there is a tie then the answer with the least total converted mana cost of all cards used wins.

Comment: Doesent modern legal require 60 cards in the deck?

Comment: The linked page describing what it means to be Modern legal is updated every few months. In order for this question to be stable over the lifetime of the site you should at the very least specify the earliest and latest sets which are allowed, and ideally provide a stable source for the banned list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By combining the solutions of Zerris and histocrat and adding [Wild Cantor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=96934), I can get down to seven cards, total CMC fifteen.

> Mulligan to a six card hand.
>  Exile [Simian Spirit Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=124474) for [image: R].
>  Cast [Ornithopter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383334).
>  Cast [Infernal Plunge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=235603) for [image: R], add [image: R][image: R][image: R].
>  Play [Glimmervoid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370425), tap for [image: G].
>  Cast [Wild Cantor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=96934) for [image: R], sacrifice it to add [image: U].
>  Play [Unexpected Results](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366248), revealing [Barren Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136048).
>  Pass the turn, sacrifice [Glimmervoid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370425).
>  Win on your next upkeep.

Old solution: Seven cards, total CMC seventeen.

> Mulligan to a six card hand.
>  Exile [Simian Spirit Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=124474) for [image: R].
>  Cast [Amulet of Vigor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=191577).
>  Play [Selesnya Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397734), tap it and return it to your hand.
>  Cast [Summer Bloom](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=84694).
>  Play [Selesnya Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397734), tap it and return it to your hand.
>  Play [Selesnya Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397734), tap it and return it to your hand.
>  Play [Selesnya Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397734), tap it and sacrifice it to cycle [Edge of Autumn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243442).
>  Cast [Deconstruct](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=49060) paying [image: G][image: G][image: G] on [Amulet of Vigor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=191577).
>  Cast [Barren Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136048).
>  Pass the turn and win on your next upkeep.

Comment: +1, Nice job. Even though you have the best T2 win I think I'll accept Zerris's answer because of the impressive T1 win.

Comment: @IvoBeckers respectively that doesn't make sense, if you ask a question you should accept the answer that best answers your question, not the one that best did something else.

Comment: @IvoBecker quoting a very wise puzzler: 'Technically the contest wasn't about earliest turn but least cards used on turn 2' -Ivobecker

Comment: @DrunkWolf yeah you're right. I have changed it  now :)

Answer (score 9):

Let's see...

**Got it on turn 1 unkeep with 10 cards, 27 CMC.  Thanks to @Ninety-Three for greatly improving my sloppy-but-hilarious first turn 1 solution!**

> **Wow You Got Lucky:**
>
>
>  Go second, mulligan once. During opponent's turn one end step:
>
>
>  Exile Simian Spirit Guide x2 for RR
>
>
>  Desperate Ritual x3 for RR > RRRRR
>
>
>  Manamorphose for RR, getting UR and drawing a card
>
>
>  Manamorphose for RR, getting UG and drawing a card
>
>
>  Quicken for U drawing a card
>
>
>  Unexpected Results for UGRR, revealing Barren Glory, put it into play
>
>
>  Continue into your turn one upkeep, win the game.

My older, un-optimized turn-one solution

> **Wow You Got *Really* Lucky:**
>
>
>  Go second. During opponent's turn one end step:
>
>
>  Exile Simian Spirit Guide x2 for RR
>
>
>  Desperate Ritual x2 for RR, RR > RRRR
>
>
>  Manamorphose for RR, getting GG, drawing 1 (3 cards, RRGG floating)
>
>
>  Violent Outburst for RRG, cascading into Wheel of Fate and playing it, discarding Composite Golem x2, drawing 7 (7 cards, G floating)
>
>
>  Exile Simian Spirit Guide x2 for RR
>
>
>  Violent Outburst for RRG, cascading into Living End, returning both Composite Golems (4 cards, nothing floating)
>
>
>  Sacrifice both Composite Golems for WWUUBBRRGG
>
>
>  Quicken for U, drawing 1 (4 cards, WWUBBRRGG floating)
>
>
>  Unexpected Results for UGWW, revealing Barren Glory, put it into play
>
>
>  One with Nothing for B, discard the rest of your hand
>
>
>  Continue into your turn one upkeep, win the game.

-- Previous turn 2 wins ---

Down to 7 cards, total CMC 19!

> **Very Expected Results**
>
>
>  *---Mulligan to 5---*
>
>
>  Exile Simian Spirit Guide for R
>
>
>  Glimmervoid, tap for R
>
>
>  Desperate Ritual x2 for RR, RR > RRRR
>
>
>  Manamorphose for RR > GU, drawing Unexpected Results
>
>
>  Unexpected Results for RRGU, revealing Barren Glory, play it for 0
>
>
>  Pass Turn, sacrificing Glimmervoid
>
>
>  Win on next Upkeep

8 cards, total CMC 15

> **Amulet Bloom is a good Modern deck, let's just play that!**
>
>
>  Exile Simian Spirit Guide for R
>
>
>  Amulet of Vigor for R
>
>
>  Selesnya Sanctuary, untap, tap for GW, return to hand
>
>
>  Summer Bloom for GW
>
>
>  Selesnya Sanctuary, untap, tap for GW, return to hand
>
>
>  Amulet of Vigor for G
>
>
>  Selesnya Sanctuary, untap, tap for GW, untap, tap for GW, return to hand
>
>
>  Selesnya Sanctuary, untap, tap for GW, untap, tap for GW, cycle Edge of Autumn, sacrificing the Sanctuary and drawing Claws of Gix
>
>
>  Claws of Gix for 0
>
>
>  Barren Glory for WWWWGG
>
>
>  Sacrifice both Amulets of Vigor and Claws of Gix to Claws of Gix for GGW
>
>
>  Pass Turn
>
>
>  Win on next Upkeep  (Simian Spirit Guide exiled, both Amulets of Vigor sacrificed to Claws of Gix, Claws of Gix sacrificed to itself, land sacrificed to Edge of Autumn)

Comment: Very impressive!

Comment: Oh wait, you don't have an empty hand I guess, so it wouldn't trigger

Comment: Of, you're right, you need no cards in hand.  Easy enough... one sec...

Comment: I think this counts as 8 cards And your previous answer actually as 7. But still the best so far!

Comment: Oh, I can't count.  8 it is.

Comment: Although, per  "If a card is discarded, exiled, milled or anything else to pay for an additional cost or because of an effect of another card it is not counted towards your card count," I might be able to discount my land...  :p

Comment: Your Hellcarver solution still leaves the demon itself on the battlefield.

Comment: Man, I need to read effects more closely.  Okay, yeah, can't beat my first one then.

Comment: @Zerris I saw this question and thought, "oh man, I should share this one with zerris, he would love it". And then you already had top answer.

Comment: Players do not get priority during the untap step. Your first opportunity to do anything other than put Leylines into play is during the upkeep step, at which point it's too late to trigger Barren Glory that turn.

Comment: Fair enough - do it at the end of your opponent's turn when you go second, then.  Still before your first turn.

Comment: That works. Why not go the much simpler route of mull to six, SSG, SSG, Ritual, Ritual, Ritual, Manamorphose (UG), Manamorphose (UG), Quicken, Unexpected Results? You can even use Gemstone Caverns (and no mulligan) instead of an SSG to reduce your total CMC.

Comment: You can't use Gemstone without a way to kill it off after, which costs at least one "card" for cycling.  The rest of your answer works as is, though - I was trying to solve a different sub-issue in one of my other solutions, which is how I ended up up here; yours is a *much* more efficient variant of it.  Do you want that solution for yourself, or can I post it with credit to you for the optimization?

Comment: Go ahead and post, I feel like you deserve most of the credit for coming up with the turn 1 trick, I was just adopting an existing solution to it. PS: Instead of mull to 6 and two manamorphoses, use a full 7, one manamorphose and one Wild Cantor.

Comment: Can't Wild Cantor at instant speed, so that doesn't help us out, sadly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a turn 1 version using 4 cards and 13 mana.

> Play [Calciform pools](http://magiccards.info/ts/en/270.html), pass turn, play plains, charge pools, pass turn charge pools, pass turn, etc until we start the turn with 6 counters on the pools: Tap pools, plains, remove 6 counters => play [Karn, liberated](http://magiccards.info/mm2/en/4.html), exile with +4 [Barren Glory](http://magiccards.info/fut/en/3.html) (pass turn) exile [Living End](http://magiccards.info/ts/en/115.html) with +4 ability(pass turn) Ult, restart game, muligan to 0, put Barren Glory into play, win on first upkeep. 4 cards used (exiled living end doesn't count), 12 mana total, turn 1.

If that somehow doesn't rock your boat, here's a simple and awesome 8

> mountain, [Simian spirit guide](http://magiccards.info/pc/en/122.html) x 4 (or x1 and [desperate ritual](http://magiccards.info/mma/en/110.html) x3 if that counts as less mana cost) to cast [Through the breach](http://magiccards.info/chk/en/193.html) into [Hellcarver Demon](http://magiccards.info/roe/en/113.html) into [Barren Glory](http://magiccards.info/fut/en/3.html)

Since Ivo made fun of my mana costs here's one that's far more boring but that beats his :P

> On the play: [Glimmervoid](http://magiccards.info/mma/en/223.html), [Simian spirit guide](http://magiccards.info/pc/en/122.html)x1 [desperate ritual](http://magiccards.info/mma/en/110.html) x4, [Manamorphose](http://magiccards.info/shm/en/211.html)  for 2 white mana-> draw and play [Barren Glory](http://magiccards.info/fut/en/3.html), sacrifice Glimmervoid eot, total cost: 19

Comment: Nice one! Mine would beat yours in mana cost though :) it's 21 by the way, I'll add that in my question

Comment: @IvoBeckers Edited with a 19

Comment: Damn, congratulations! Why didn't I think of that? Mine is actually different in only one card. And pretty stupid considering your answer. Instead of a fourth Desperate Ritual I had a Channel the Suns

Comment: Technically the contest wasn't about earliest turn but least cards used on turn 2 and I think it's a loophole that shouldn't be allowed, but nice find anyway :)

Comment: @IvoBeckers I could do it with just 4 cards that way though ;) land + chargeland, chargex6 karn, barren glory ;), I could even delay the kill to turn 2 by mulliganning to 1 and casting 2 pyrexian mana spells, but ok, i admit it's a bit loopholish. Or at least `op het randje` ;)

Comment: The Karn trick actually lets you get a five card win. Urza's Mine, Urza's Power Plant, Urza's Tower, Karn, +4 to exile Living End (which doesn't count, because you don't use its ability), +4 to exile Barren Glory, restart, win with five cards used.

Comment: @Ninety-Three as I mentioned in the comment, you can do 4 with a charge land (one of those 1,t, put charge counter on)

Comment: Doh, that's what I get for skimming the comments.

Comment: Don't you mean 13 mana, not 12?

Comment: @Ninety-Three Whoops yes, ofcourse

Answer (score 3):

I think I can do it with total CMC 12:

> Glimmervoid - R. [Memnite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=MEMNITE) - R. [Infernal Plunge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=235603) - RRR. Memnite - RRR. Infernal Plunge - RRRRR. Desperate Ritual - RRRRRR. Manamorphose - RRRRWW. Barren Glory. Total Cards: 8 Total CMC: 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 6 = 12

Comment: Looks like this could be converted to 7 cards CMC 15 by swapping out one Memnite/Infernal Plunge combo for Unexpected Results.

Comment: @Brilliand Which is what Ninety-Three's answer is